# Django template not found but file exist

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have some third-part library, templates from that library is diplayed by default.

I want to replace layout template, from which all other start inheritance.

So, in my local app I create new `layout.html` file, which contents 
`{% extends 'library:layout.html' %}`

But in that case I've got 
`TemplateDoesNotExist at /test-url/ 
test.html`

But still **Template-loader postmortem** display, that it can find file:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/path/to/app/templates/test.html (File does not exist)

Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/path/to/library/app1/templates/test.html (File does not exist)
/path/to/library/app2/templates/test.html (File does not exist)
/path/to/library/app3/templates/test.html (File exists)
```

So, in library `app3` Django found template, but for some reason do not use it. Can you help with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the `layout.html` template located?

Comment: @Alasdair it is just in root `/templates/` dir. Basically, regarding to your answer I've tried extending like `{% extends 'layout.html %}`, but still exception is about another template, that is called by view.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there isn't another missing template that is causing the error.

Your `extends` tag looks wrong. I would expect to see `library/layout.html`, not `library:layout.html`

```
{% extends 'library/layout.html' %}
```